# Positivity of alternating series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $\{a_n\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of positive real numbers such that $\limsup_n \frac{1}{n}\log a_n=-\infty$. Then
$$
 f(x)=\sum_{n\geq 0}a_n x^n
$$
converges absolutely for all $x$. Under what conditions on $\{a_n\}$ will we have $f(x)\geq 0$ for all $x\leq 0$?